# Extract parameters and values from django API using python

Tags: python, django

I require a generic method that fetches all the parameters with value.
APIs can be GET/POST I just need to extract value from it and check does it is a valid value or not.
Tried this method but it requires a specific parameter name to extract values.
`param_value = request.query_params.get('param_value')`

I require all the parameters and their value without passing name.

Comment: request.GET is providing you a key-value pair, which you can access easily

Comment: But that will restrict me to the GET method only, I also need the POST method key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate over the 2-tuples of the key and a list of values with:

```
for key, values in request.query_params.lists():
    # …
```

Comment: It works for parameters but the body part still remains.

Comment: @BhavsikAhir: you use `request.data` for the body...

Comment: Don't know why but `request.data` does not work in Django middleware. I have tried with `request.body` , but it also has some issues. Like when I get data from form and I convert it into a string using `request.body.decode()` it has unwanted lines like: `------WebKitFormBoundary4AF6lQ4QNvCXB4Ea
Content-Disposition: form-data;`